# Ruby on rails: devise http://0.0.0.0:3000/users/sign_out problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

http://0.0.0.0:3000/users/sign_in works but http://0.0.0.0:3000/users/sign_out

Routing Error

```
No route matches "/users/sign_out"
```

routes.rb:

```
  devise_for :users
  resources :posts
  root :to => "posts#index"
```

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem. It was caused by the link code that I copied from the wiki.

it was `link_to'Logout', destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete`, but devise was set up to log out via :get (`# config.sign_out_via = :get` in the initializers/devise.rb:178).

So either uncomment this line and change it to `:delete` or remove the `:method => :delete` from your link_to