# rails devise, no route matches logout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, logout, routes

Though there're lots of similar questions, i've searched for it for hours but still can not fix it.

Env
rails 3.0.9
ruby 1.9.2
devise 1.4.2

I changed the default login url using:

```
 5   resources :users
 6   devise_for :users, :path => "", :path_names => { :sign_in => 'login', :sign_out  
     => 'logout', :password => 'secret', :confirmation => 'verification', :unlock =>
     'unblock', :registration => 'register', :sign_up => 'cmon_let_me_in' }
```

And the http://localhost:3000/login works fine for me
But I include

```
 = link_to 'sign_out', destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete
```

in my application.haml, after i click it, it says that no route matchs "/logout"
Why?
Please help me.

Comment: What's the output of `rake routes`?

Comment: Have you tried googling?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6805491/ruby-on-rails-devise-http-0-0-0-03000-users-sign-out-problem/6805662#6805662

Answer (score 11):

I had a nearly identical problem and thanks to SO fixed it quite easily ([link to my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557311/no-route-matches-users-sign-out-devise-rails-3)). First, make sure you have `<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>` in your layout file "application.html.erb."

Then, in your config -> initializers -> "devise.rb" file make sure it says:

`config.sign_out_via = :delete`

and your "sign_out" code `destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete` should work.

Comment: I m using ruby 1.9.2p180, Rails 3.1.0.rc4 and devise 1.4.2.
I've <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %> in my layout file.
and using <%= link_to 'Sign out', destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %>
But still it does not work for me

Comment: In your "devise.rb" initializers file do you have `config.sign_out_via = :delete` or `config.sign_out_via = :get`? There has been a recent update to the way devise handles routes. If you're using the :delete method, you would need to have your sign_out path configured as the first option.

Comment: I am having the same problem. I have it setup correctly in the devise.rb (set to :delete) and the link_to (:method => :delete). I also am using and included JQuery. However, I still receive a 'GET' request. I also have checked the generated code and I see the following for the link_to method: <a href="/users/sign_out" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow">Logout</a>.

Comment: I recommend you checkout the answers to my question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557311/no-route-matches-users-sign-out-devise-rails-3). I would recommend going through the various problems different users have been having and you may spot something that will fix yours. If not, let me know.

Comment: I've just been having a problem with this. It's not something i'd seen before. This answer helped with my debugging though - i noticed that my javascript files weren't loading (in a very early stage of development). I fixed my JS files to load as expected and the routes worked.

Answer (score 5):

A little late to this party, but here's some help from another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17182137/devise-no-route-matches-get-users-sign-out)

Specify your method:

```
<%= link_to "sign out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %>
```

Answer (score 4):

Set `config.sign_out_via = :get` in `config/initializers/devise.rb` to use the following code for your sign out link.

```
<%= link_to "Sign Out", destroy_user_session_path %>
```

Comment: Downvote because this is less secure than using post + csrf token.