# devise No route matches [GET] "/users/sign_out"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am trying to use Desive authentication.

Everything went smoothly until this point (sign up and sign in).

But I cannot make the sign out link work. I checked the destination link with `rake routes`; `destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)         devise/sessions#destroy`.

But when I put `<%= link_to "sign out", destroy_user_session_path %>` on the home page and clicked on the link, I received this error; `No route matches [GET] "/users/sign_out"`.

As an aside, I'm currently running Ruby-2.0.0-p195, and Rails 3.2.13

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use method DELETE

```
<%= link_to "sign out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %>
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to pass "method: delete" to send as DELETE request. If you dont set "method: delete", then it will be sent as GET request.

```
<%= link_to "Sign Out" ,destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %>
```